# How to control size of bin in python to using numpy.histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I try to control bin using with numpy package as below code

`bin_hights, bin_width = np.histogram(get_pdf,density=True)`

is there are any method to control bin size to use numpy package?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using:

```
numpy.histogram(a, bins=15)
numpy.histogram(a, bins=10, range=None, normed=None, weights=None, density=None)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html